# Preventing Same Value from getting saved again onto DB Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a table named user histories and a message will get saved on to that table along with the user ID. I also don't want same message to get saved again from the same user.
Here is the part in my controller that saves the message.

```
    if delete == 1
      if UserHistory.where(comments:message, user_id:id).present?
        self.update_attributes(points: (self.points + point))
        UserHistory.where(comments:message, user_id:id).first.destroy        
      end
    elsif UserHistory.where(comments:message, user_id:id).present?
    else  
      self.update_attributes(points: (self.points + point))
      UserHistory.create(comments:message, user_id:id)        
    end
```

In this code if the message with same id is found i have given no action and else create a new field.

My Problem is its all working fine in my local machine. But when i deployed to development in my server its not working always.. Some times same messages from same user gets saved again. Why does this happen? Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this in `UserHistory` model

```
validates_uniqueness_of :comments, :scope => :user_id
```

Update : In `else` block just reverse the lines so that validation fires before the points are updated

```
else      
  user_history = UserHistory.create(comments:message, user_id:id)
  self.update_attributes(points: (self.points + point)) unless user_history.blank?
end
```

Comment: There is a point updation..
self.update_attributes(points: (self.points + point))
so even if i write this in my model the point updation takes place.. I want to prevent it from that too

Comment: Can you tell me in which line of code you are facing the problem?

Comment: see this part
else  
   self.update_attributes(points: (self.points + point))
   UserHistory.create(comments:message, user_id:id)        
end
If no mesages for corresponding user is found database has to be updated and it should add one point to the existing point..

Comment: You might also want to consider adding a unique index to the table. http://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations

Comment: @RSB Should i remove elsif part from my original code?